# Producing Lines of Text without underfull \hbox errors

Tags: line-breaking, memoir, badness

I'm preparing a colophon for a book I'm writing in `memoir` class. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{5pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

~\vfill

\textbf{My Awesome Book}, \textsc{\nth{3} Edition} \\
Copyright \textcopyright{} \the\year{} John Doe.\\
Some Rights Reserved.\\
Last edited: \today.\\

\begin{multicols}{2}
    Some Text\\
    More Text\\

    \footnotesize
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output (excerpted):

[image]

Everything looks as it should. There's just one problem: compiling this code (with `lualatex`, incidentally), gives the following warnings:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--20


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 22--24
```

These warnings disappear when the line breaks `\\` are removed. Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm trying to do without producing these warnings? Furthermore, is there a more "correct" way to have lines of text which aren't organized into paragraphs?

Comment: never end a paragraph with `\\ ` it will always give an infinite(10000) bad line (the `\\ ` that are being used for line breaks are fine and do not give any warning) just the ones after `\today.` and after `More Text`

Comment: What is the recommended way to produce that sort of output then? It seems like the sort of thing which often comes up.

Comment: just remove the `\\ ` and allow `\parskip` to add space or if you need extra space add a blank line then `\bigskip` or `\vspace{3.898cm}` or whatever you need